How to use rsync without creating annoying underscore files?
I am using rsync as follows
rsync --inplace -aEu -v  --delete --exclude=".DS_Store" --exclude="._*" /Users/alex/Documents /Volumes/BACKUP/Documents

to sync the files and folders from my Documents folders to a hard drive (with a FAT32 partition). However, while copying, it seems that underscore files are created, like
._file.py

How to avoid creating them on the backup?

What filesystem is on the destination?

the filesystem on the harddrive is FAT32

@Alex that comment should be part of your question and not a comment.

Before eliminating these files, have you considered that they may be housing metadata (extended attributes) that may be important to preserve? More details available here.

The dash-files are being created to support the extended attributes from the source filesystem.  FAT32 does not support extended attributes.
If you're using rsync v3.x e.g. from Homebrew, try adding the --no-xattrs flag to your rsync command.
If you're using the OS-bundled version 2.6.9 (/usr/bin/rsync), then as Gordon Davisson points out below, removing the -E flag should stop trying to copy extattrs.
Backing up a step, does the external drive have to be FAT32? Reformatting it as APFS or HFS+ would avoid these issues. I assume you know that and chose FAT32 so you could read the files on a Windows PC.

If this is macOS' built-in version of rsync (v2.6.9, with some macOS-specific extensions), removing the -E option will probably do it.
